# How to track two different internal site search queries

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm learning how to get my hands dirty with Google Analytics and stumbled upon a doubt which seems not to be very common as I search the internet for solutions.

I'm trying to set up Google Analytics for a website that has two different internal searches, one for its products and another which is meant to search its FAQs.

They seem to use different search query parameters, but apparently, both are page path search based (difference is that the product search has categories and the FAQ is a simple string search).

**Products search:** /en/search/?location=test%20search&type_space=car&check_in=19%2F01%2F2018&check_out=19%2F01%2F2018

**FAQ search query:** /en/faq-search/test%20search

**Question is**: is there a way to setup Google Analytics to track both search terms as Internal Search Terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading dozens of articles, I ended up discovering that the most correct path to be followed would be to either change the page path with GTM or ask my web developers to restructure the website code to include in the URL the necessary search query and search categories parameters.

Nonetheless, there are also people out there whose access to a web-developer is very limited or whose company's process to change the website code would take months. So the solution to make Google Analytics track both website search URIs, without any further code change would be to do the following:

1. Create a GA Test view so that you can test it prior to doing the same changes in your reporting view.
2. Within GA Administration > click Filters > Add New Filter > Name it as you want > Filter type: custom > select advanced >

   **Field A -> Extract A (Request URI)** 
   ((/en/search/)|(/en/faq-search/))(.*?)($|\?location=)(.*?)($|\&type_space=)(.*?)($|\&check_in=)(.*?)($|\&check_out=)(.*)

   **Output To -> Constructor** $A4$A6

   **Hit save** > test and see both search queries being saved in google analytics as search terms

Answer (score 0):

Google Site Search uses query parameters.  There is a search term parameter,  and a search category parameter.  You configure both of those in the view admin screen.

You need to send a hit to GA with the query parameters encoded.  I recommend using GTM to rewrite the page path dimension to include parameters for search term and search category.

Comment: Thanks Pat! I've researched a lot since I posted this, dozens of articles, how-tos and tutorials read. While your advice is very useful and I could have done that (I actually ended up changing my site search's URI structure to include parameters), I would like to post the solution for tracking both of the aforementioned URIs in GA without further change. I'll post below the solution for that, made with regex.